# Capturing Rscript errors in an output file

Tags: linux, r, rscript

Unlike the similar command `R CMD BATCH` which by default produces an output file which contains any error messages which would cause the execution of a script to halt, I have not been able to find a way to do this with `Rscript`. I have tried using a pipe in my linux shell to achieve this:

```
RScript --no-save --no-restore --verbose myRfile.R > outputFile.Rout
```

but this will only pipe over any output that occurred before an error occurs, so the file `outputFile.R` doesn't contain any error information. Does anyone know how to get the capture any errors that occur in executing an R file using `RScript` and saving it to a file?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
Rscript --no-save --no-restore --verbose myRfile.R > outputFile.Rout 2> errorFile.Rout
```

To put the output and error in the same file (assuming sh/bash)

```
Rscript --no-save --no-restore --verbose myRfile.R > outputFile.Rout 2>&1
```

Comment: Amazing. But could you educate me. What's the `2>` syntax mean?

Comment: `2>` means redirect standard error (file descriptor number `2`).

Comment: what if I woould like to APPEND to a file that already exists?

Comment: Appending to an existing file can be done using `>>` instead of `>`: `Rscript --no-save --no-restore --verbose myRfile.R >> outputFile.Rout 2>&1`

Comment: In the R outfile, I got `--no-echo --no-restore --no-save --no-restore --file` even when I used the commands as given in the answer. What does `--no-echo` mean .. do not print?