# Rscript logfile with input, errors and output

Tags: r

Is there a way to **fully log** (stdin, stdout, stderror) a **R session** executed via **Rscript** in batch mode?

I know, that I can use `R CMD BATCH` to log the full session of a batch job. I also know how to write errors and output into a logfile using `Rscript` but since it is often said that `R CMD BATCH` is a relict from the old days and one should use `Rscript`, I was wondering if it can also log everything.

*I suppose it is impossible but I am not sure - neither do I know why.*

Comment: Did you try `Rscript --save`?

Comment: @agstudy  This saves the workspace but it does not log anything -- right.

Comment: how about `-e "sink('logfile.txt')"` ?

Comment: nope, that doesnt do anything except creating 'logfile.txt' ... I tried: ``Rscript -e "sink('logfile.txt')" getQuotes.r``

Comment: There is this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008139/capturing-rscript-errors-in-an-output-file which tells you how to log stdout and stderror. So to answer the question do we just need to log stdin?

Comment: **YES, Why not?** ... I want to see where the errors happened what ran through and what might have given a warning or whatever. Separating might be nice sometimes but having all three in one file is neat most of the times when human instead of machine has to look at the stuff.