# R output when script is run form python

Tags: python, r

I would like to run an R script from python, and capture the output into a .Rout type file. The R script takes command line arguments. I am struggling... Minimal working example follows.

R script:

```
job_reference <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
arg1 <- job_reference[1]
arg2 <- job_reference[2]
arg3 <- job_reference[3]
arg4 <- job_reference[4]
print("***")
print(paste(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4))
print("***")
```

python script:

```
import subprocess
arg1 = 'a'
arg2 = 'b'
arg3 = 'c'
arg4 = 'd'
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/Rscript",  "--no-save", "--no-restore", "--verbose", "print_letters.R",  arg1, arg2,  arg3, arg4, ">", "outputFile.Rout", "2>&1"])
```

The last line in the python script is via [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008139/capturing-rscript-errors-in-an-output-file).

If I run the python script, the "outputFile.Rout" is *not* produced. However the python output includes:

```
running
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R --slave --no-restore --no-save --no-restore --file=print_letters.R --args a b c d > outputFile.Rout'
```

and when I run that from the command line without involving python the output file *is* produced. Note that I have tried specifying full paths to output files, etc.

Can anyone explain i) what is happening here; ii) how I can run an R script from python with the R script accepting command line arguments *and* producing an Rout type file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## i) what is happening here

The `Rscript` call you grabbed makes use of a shell feature called i/o redirection.  In particular, the end of that command, `> outputFile.Rout 2>&1` is a special shell feature that means roughly *redirect all the output from the command into the file "outputFile.Rout", oh and also redirect standard error to standard out so it ends up in that file as well*.

From the [`subprocess` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments),

> `shell=False` disables all shell based features

in other words, the default for `subprocess.call()` is to run the command without using the shell, so you don't get access to the shell based features.  Instead the '>' and 'outputFile.Rout' for instance are passed directly as args to R, just like `a`.

## ii) run R script with output redirect

While there a couple ways to go about this, such as using `os.system()` or  passing `shell=True` to `subprocess.call()` and passing the command as a string, the recommended way is just to use the machinery in `subprocess` to do the equivalent i/o redirection:

```
with open('outputFile.Rout','w') as fileobj:
    subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/Rscript",  "--no-save", "--no-restore",
                     "--verbose", "print_letters.R", 
                     arg1, arg2,  arg3, arg4], 
                     stdout=fileobj, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```